# jQuery SVG nested groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I need to generate an SVG nested group with jQuerySVG or RaphaëlJS. The latter doesn't support groups, so I chose the former.

What I need:

```
<g transform="translate(300, 300)">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-100" />
    <g transform="translate(0, -100) rotate(20)">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-100" />
    </g>
</g>
```

The website is down at the moment, but checking the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20101112121735/http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) for documentation I can't find a way to give an element two different groups:

```
svg.line(g, 10, 80, 140, 70);
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
svg.line(g, g2, 10, 80, 140, 70);
```

Any different approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to doc you can do this:

```
g = svg.group();
g2 = svg.group(g);
svg.line(g, 10, 80, 140, 70);
svg.line(g2, 10, 80, 140, 70);
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't see that you could add a parent group when creating a new one. Thanks!